# Converting linear unit to string for adding to file name in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, parameters

In ModelBuilder I have a 'search distance' parameter that is a linear unit data type that I am trying to convert to a string so that it can be added to the end of a file's name so the user knows what the selection parameters were for future reference.

I have the file output name set up with in line variables that successfully pass the *string* parameters along , but not this linear unit type. I also have a calculate values tool that will find and replace the spaces the linear unit outputs. I've tried a simple str(search distance) conversion, but I haven't tried passing the first few characters yet into another variable.

[image: The tool at the top is where I'm getting errors.]

Comment: You may enter more than 1 inline variable in Calculate Value.  You just need a defined parameter for linear unit and I think the linear unit data type behaves like string you can parse with Python (all of which I think you've done but without an illustration I can't be sure).  So if your output for Calculate Value is defined as string, you can then add the parsed value you've shown as str(search distance) much like the some of the examples here:  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm

Comment: @T.WayneWhitley if you can add an example or two this may be worth adding as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by taking the first character of the "Search Distance" Linear Unit parameter and then concatenating the units onto it since I will only be running this selection in meters. I had also forgotten to add quotes around the inline variable when I was converting it from Linear Unit to string.
[image: fixed solution]